# Find out the max rainfall

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to Python and `numpy` but have to extract information from a text file. The file has over 17,000 rows of information, and I want to get the "wettest year on record" for my project. The first column `[0]` has the years listed from 1962 to 2011 and has data for every month `[1]` in that year.

This is an example of the text file:

```
1962 01 134.6 12.5 22 
1962 02 77.2 11.2 17 
1962 03 73.6 13.4 13 
1962 04 68.6 20.6 17 
1962 05 80.7 22.7 16 
1962 06 50.2 28.3 11 
1962 07 92.2 18.5 15 
1962 08 99.4 25.8 19 
1962 09 122.4 31.1 19 
1962 10 42.6 15.1 12 
1962 11 105.5 23.7 14 
1962 12 86.4 23.6 18
```

The other columns are total rainfall `[2]` most rainfall in a day `[3]` and number of rainy days `[4]`.

I want to find what was the wettest year on record, but don't know where to start!

Comment: Start here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: I'd suggest that you have a look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my query!

Answer (score 0):

17 000 rows ? for 50   years of 12 months I found 600 rows with your description of the data file but anyway, assuming the data are in a file called 'data.txt' and each row is ended with a newline (doesn't appear in your example), and the file begins with this informations, here is a possible solution

```
wettest_year = 0
max_rainfall = 0
with open('data.txt') as flux:
    for current_year in range(1962, 2011 + 1):
        current_year_rainfall = 0
        for current_month in range(12):
            row = flux.readline().split()
            month_rainfall = float(row[2])
            current_year_rainfall += month_rainfall
        if current_year_rainfall > max_rainfall:
            wettest_year = current_year
            max_rainfall = current_year_rainfall
```

wettest_year holds the answer

ps : if this is really a file of 17 000 lines, you will need to seek to the position where the data begins before entered the for loop

ps2 : assuming "wettest year" is the one with the most total rainfall